# stopping service manually in widget

Tags: android, android-service

I have a ImageView in Widget , when ever i click over it i start a service using `getService` as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);    
PendingIntent pendingServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0 , 
            intent , 0);
```

and in turn MyService class send a message to handler in `onCreate` of `MyService` to start the service with a message

```
  myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_FETCH_DATA);
```

Now i want to stop that service using that ImageView , so how can i do that ? My application demands to stop this service manually by widget so that i am not using  `stopSelf()`

Comment: hunt,when you want to stop this Service means on ImageView Click if yes then see [Widget is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671596/how-do-i-start-an-activity-when-my-widget-is-clicked/9671968#9671968)?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);   this is how i did it in a onReceive when a ImageView is clicked is this the way right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android Service doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) talks about stopping a service. Specifically, it mentions the

```
context.stopService(Intent service);
```

method. You can read more about this method in the [Android Context doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29).

Hope this helps!